# Handle any unhandled click event in wpf app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF app with a custom context menu which works great, but I want to ensure that if a user clicks off the context menu onto another part of the app the context menu closes.   I have a global app event I can call to close the menu so I am really looking for how best to handle the click event itself.

Bonus question: How can I also handle people switching to another app (i.e. the app loses focus)

**Update**
As per the comments I have tried using an EventTrigger but it didnt work as expected.  It didnt fire if I clicked off the control, it only fired if something else specifically got focus

```
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseRightButtonUp}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
```

Comment: Would this be a case of contextMenu.lostFocus(); me.close()(or whatever your close function is) ?

Comment: Its a custom context menu - I'm using a `Popup` and using MVVM so would rather not have any code behind the view.

Comment: Maybe your `Menu` should use `CaptureMouse()` to be notified of what the mouse does.

Comment: Can you just grab the LostFocus with an eventtrigger and fire off a CallMethodAction to close the popup? Could do that in xaml only.

Comment: @ChrisW. This is exactly what I tried but it didnt work as expected.  I'll update my question with code but essentially it never seemed to fire if I clicked off the control

Answer (score 0):

Why not maintain the behavior of your context menu with the relevant control that supports that task and just present the visual makeup of that control differently by using a controltemplate.

That's why controltemplates exist just for that reason.